# \vspace* (star) moves text above it

Tags: spacing, starred-version

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaa

\vspace*{100cm}

bbb

\end{document}
```

I would expect `aaa` to be placed at page one, then to see 100cm of white space (distributed over many pages) and finally `bbb`. However, page 1 is empty, then page 2 has `aaa` and then the document ends. Why?

Comment: Because the default papersize is `letter` or `a4` and not `x cm by 100cm`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But why is the white space placed before? I mean, the starred `\vspace` should just ignore the page break and continue with the spacing, not place it before.

Comment: @Simon It doesn't work that way. `\vspace*` creates just one indivisible space. If you want it to go for many pages you should create a macro (that I don't think it's trivial).

Comment: @Manuel So, `\vspace*` just adds the desired spacing, either before or after the text? Does not seem too useful to me, then... Also, where is `bbb` gone in my example?

Comment: `bbb` has  gone exactly where you specified it, around a metre off the page, TeX will have warned about that in the log. I'm not sure what you mean by "before or after the text", the space is added at the point the `\vspace` command appears (or if used mid-paragraph, after the line that had the vspace command)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By "before or after the text" I mean that some white space is placed before `aaa`, which is shifted to the second page. The `\vspace*` appears after `aaa` so I would expect that no white space is added before it. Anyway, this behavior has been explained in Ulrike's answer.

Comment: That's what I thought you meant, no that doesn't happen. The space from the vspace is added after `aaa`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The vspace is one large block. So you get an overful box and the bbb is somewhere outside the page. The aaa is moved along with the space to page 2 as there is no break point before the \vspace*. To get what you want you should better use smaller vspace in a loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

aaa

\foreach\x in {1,2,...,100}
{\penalty0 \vspace*{1cm}}

bbb

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could also explain why this “one large block” is moved from the first to the second page, but is not carried over any further; I mean, the well-known story of the `\write-1{}` that is issued at the `\begin{document}` and that makes the `\topskip` glue of the first page (and of the first page only) a permissible breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks! In the end, I used your solution for my template. It is very easy to read and to use :)

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially getting a big chunk of indivisible white space and because of a feature of LaTeX, if the first page turns out to be overfull, a blank page is produced instead and the contents moved on to the next page, which will again be overfull. The “bbb” disappears about one meter below the bottom edge of the paper.

Here's a `\breakablevspace` macro that doesn't suffer from the problem: it will leave the requested space, dividing it in the necessary blank pages. Enjoy, I'm not going to give explanations: read the books. `;-)` Suffices it to say that the space turns out to be 2845.27559pt, that is, exactly 100cm.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\bvs@temp
\newcommand{\breakablevspace}[1]{%
  \par
  \bvs@temp=#1\relax
  \breakable@vspace
}
\newcommand{\breakable@vspace}{%
  \ifdim\dimexpr
    \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
      \textheight
    \else
      \pagegoal-\pagetotal
    \fi
   \relax<\bvs@temp
    \bvs@temp=\dimexpr\bvs@temp
      \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
        -\textheight
      \else
        -\pagegoal+\pagetotal
      \fi
    \relax
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \newpage
    \hrule height\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  \breakable@vspace
  {\vspace*{\bvs@temp}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

aaa

\breakablevspace{100cm}

bbb

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice and amusing at the same time; but I have three remarks.  (1) Why `\vspace*{\fill}` and not just `\null`?  (2) Why `\hrule height\z@`?  (3) Aren’t you getting 100cm + 10pt, due to the `\topskip` glue on the last page?

Comment: The `\hrule` is exactly for avoiding the insertion of topskip glue in the empty pages before the computation of the yet-to-insert space is performed. The macro can possibly be improved, I wrote it just for fun.

Comment: To my knowledge, a `\hrule` does not prevent TeX from adding the `\topskip` glue.  Let me check with `\showoutput`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti If you look at `\pagegoal` at the appropriate spot, you see it's `\maxdimen` when a page has already been filled. Whether the topskip glue is added is irrelevant then.

Comment: I don’t follow you: (1) `\pagegoal` is `\maxdimen` when the current page contains no boxes, not even a rule box (p. 114, l. 32); (2) `\vspace*{\fill}` already inserts a rule; and, (3) the `\topskip` glue on the *last* page *is* relevant.  But maybe we can continue on chat, if you wish so.  (But remember that I can only type *slowly*! :-)

Comment: I confirm: `\hrule` does not prevent TeX from adding the `\topskip` glue.

Comment: Amazing macro, many thanks :) One thing: is there a reason to prefer a macro like this to a much more simple and readable trick like Ulrike's one? Thanks again!

Comment: @Simon I'd go for Ulrike's, `;-)`

Comment: @Simon: egreg's solution is exact, mine solution isn't. I assumed that you want roughly 100cm.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I do not need an exact spacing (and 100cm was just an example). Your solution is perfect for what I need, although I acknowledge that egreg's solution is "more correct".